# $f(x,y)=yg(x)$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Let $g\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and define $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=yg(x)$.
>
> Show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if $g$ is continuous at $0$.

So $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if $f$ can be written as
$$
 f(x,y)=f(0,0)+L(x,y)+R(x,y) 
$$
where $L$ is a linear map consisting out of the partial derivatives which are $0$ with respect to $x$ and $g(0)$ in respect to $y$.

How can I show that $R(x,y)$ goes to $0$. I'm having trouble to conclude the right limit.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: First guess the limit. What would ${\partial f(0,0) \over \partial x}, {\partial f(0,0) \over \partial y}$ be?

Comment: ∂f(0,0)/∂x=o    ∂f(0,0)/∂y=g(0). Well the limit must be zero anyway, for my statement to be true but i dont understand how i need to built the limit of R(x,y) in the end i want something like R(x,y) has a limit at 0 if g(0) is continous in 0. sorry for not using mathjax

Comment: Well, you have guessed the limit correctly, what are the remaining issues?

Comment: $\lim _{ (x,y)\rightarrow (0,0) }{ \frac { R(x,y) }{ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } }  } =0 } $ i cant see how R(x,y) should look like (i know that this is a rather dumb issue)

Comment: What about $R(x,y) = f(x,y)-L(x,y)-f(0,0) = y g(x) - yg(0)-0 = y(g(x)-g(0))$?

Comment: thanks! i was at a loss, its actually kinda obvious

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have identified what $L(x,y)$ should look like, i.e.
$$
L(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) x+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)y = 0\cdot x + g(0)y = g(0)y
$$
then the only "sensible" choice for $R(x,y)$ is what remains:
$$
R(x,y) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} f(x,y) - f(0,0) - L(x,y) = yg(x) - 0 - g(0)y = y(g(x)-g(0).
$$

So we need to show that this satisfies what it should, that is
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\lvert R(x,y)\rvert}{\lVert (x,y)\rVert_2} = 0 \tag{1}.
$$

To do so, fix any $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $\delta > 0$ be (by continuity of $g$ at $0$) such that $\lvert g(x)-g(0)\rvert \leq \varepsilon$ whenever $\lvert x\rvert \leq \delta$.

Then, for any $(x,y)$ such that $\lVert (x,y)\rVert_2 = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq \delta$, we get that $\lvert x\rvert \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq \delta$, and thus
$$
\frac{\lvert R(x,y)\rvert}{\lVert (x,y)\rVert_2}
= \frac{\lvert y\rvert\cdot \lvert g(x)-g(0)\rvert}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\leq \varepsilon \cdot \frac{\lvert y\rvert}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\leq \varepsilon
$$
the last inequality as $\lvert y\rvert = \sqrt{y^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this shows (1), and therefore that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.